# Sort json array in dot liquid or logic app

Tags: liquid, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard, dotliquid

I wish to get most recent collection from my json array based on created date in logic app variable or using dot liquid transformation.

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "id": "957777746054",
        "owner": "jFinder",
        "created": "2021-03-30T04:12:18+0000",
        "updated": "2021-03-30T04:12:18+0000",
        "revision": "1"
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "id": "957777725902",
        "owner": "jFinder",
        "created": "2021-03-29T16:50:21+0000",
        "updated": "2021-03-29T16:50:21+0000",
        "revision": "1"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

My idea was to sort this by "created" and then iterate over to pick first/last. But sort logic is not working. Can you help?

My liquid map start with

```
{% assign current = content.properties | Sort: "created" %}

{%- for item in current %}{"id" : "{{ current.id }}",do whatever} {%- endfor -%}
```

this always returns nill. I replaced created with id to see if that works but also didnt help

Answer (score 0):

My answer is half baked and this is untested, but I think you have your liquid a little confused.  I think it should look like this ...

```
{% assign current = content | Sort: "properties.created" %}

{%- for item in current %}{"id" : "{{ current.properties.id }}",do whatever} {%- endfor -%}
```

Your array is contained within the `content` property which means you should be looping over that and then referencing lower level, sub properties through the `property` property.

Now, if that doesn't work, my suggestion would be to look at using the `Advanced Data Operations` connector.  There's an operation there called **Sort Object Array** ...

[image: Sort Object Array]

... and it takes in an array of complex objects and will sort it based on your instructions.

Documentation can be found here ... https://www.statesolutions.com.au/sort-object-array/

So in relation to your requirement, this flow demonstrates the usage ...

[image: Flow]

I loaded your data in to a variable called **Data** and then in the next step, I refer to the underlying `Content` array and then sort it by `properties.created` in an **ascending** order.

It's a little bit hard to show in a single screenshot but you can see it's ordered it as instructed to ...

[image: Result]

Comment: Sorry to mention but I can use only built-in/In-app connectors in my logic app due to network restrictions

Comment: also above liquid transformation logic wont work

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, I could get desired results following the below process.

Here is the sample json I used adding some more data to yours.

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "created": "2021-03-30T04:12:18+0000",
        "id": "957777746054",
        "owner": "jFinder",
        "revision": "1",
        "updated": "2021-03-30T04:12:18+0000"
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "created": "2021-03-29T16:50:21+0000",
        "id": "957777725902",
        "owner": "jFinder",
        "revision": "1",
        "updated": "2021-03-29T16:50:21+0000"
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "created": "2021-04-30T04:12:18+0000",
        "id": "957777746054",
        "owner": "jFinder",
        "revision": "1",
        "updated": "2021-03-30T04:12:18+0000"
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "created": "2021-01-30T04:12:18+0000",
        "id": "957777746054",
        "owner": "jFinder",
        "revision": "1",
        "updated": "2021-03-30T04:12:18+0000"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Flow in my logic apps

[image]

[image]

I am trying to compare 2 dates from the json and updated `Ticks` and `FinalObject` variables with the latest date's ticks and the current item.

Results:

[image]